# How to reload mod_jk

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, mod-jk

I work under Ubuntu. Each time I restart apache2, it tells me that jk_module is already loaded, so it skips it. Problem : I think I misconfigured something, so I changed it, but since it is not reloaded, change are not taken. So, How can I reload mod_jk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that the module is in your configuration two places at once. So go through your configs, and search for "jk_module" or just "jk", if you see it load twice, that's most likely the issue. Just remove or comment out the first or second time it does it and it should work.

Also remember to look through the configs in conf.d